# Symfony: REST web-service, layout VS. decorator

Tags: php, rest, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Symfony turns layout off if the requested format is different to 'html'. That seems okay. However, if the term 'layout' is just used for decorators it doesn't make sense anymore. I need a decorator which contains something like `{"success": true}` .

Should I prevent Symfony from turning off my layout and tell it to use my decorator 'layout.json.php', instead? At which point is Symfony disabling it - at which point can I re-enable it? Do you have a better idea?

Cheers, fishbone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout is mainly used for content that is usually static and in all pages (like header, menu, footer, etc). For a REST service you dont need any of that, you only have to 'decorate' the response in the given format (json, xml, yaml).

I think that is usefull that symfony automatically disables layout when the request format is different than 'html' so that your only concern is doing the template (view) only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->setLayout('layout.json');` in your action